# PHP Implode returning single entry

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use implode() in a script to return the result of an SQL query as a string so I can insert it into another table, however whenever I manage to get the implode to return anything it will only return a single result, even though the query returns more than one result.

*Note*: my PHP is not the strongest and I am using pre-existing code and reworking it, which is why a lot of the code will look like it's meant for a JSON API.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


 if ($rows) {
     $response["success"] = 1;
     $response["message"] = "Events Scheduled!";
     $response["events"]   = array();

 foreach ($rows as $row) {
     $post             = array();
$post["id"]  = $row["id"];
     $post["message"] = $row["message"];
     $post["pin"] = $row["pin"];

     array_push($response["events"], $post);
     $matstring=implode("', '",$post);
    }
}
```

When echo'd out I get:

> 3', 'Test to check multiple entries are in array for when the check is made, this should be seen.', '12345

imploding $response['events'] returns "Array, Array" and everything else I have tried returns nothing. Where should I look to get the other entry?

Comment: If you want to insert it into another table, doing it wholly on the SQL level would be preferred.

Comment: It's a scheduling system that needs to execute some PHP when the time is right. I have looked into SQL triggering but this is the only method that works for me unfortunately.

Comment: ... triggering? I would not advise that. I'm just saying there's `INSERT ... SELECT...` and `UPDATE ... JOIN...`  statements. But without further data I couldn't tell you, so if you're convinced you need to cycle data from the database through your application just to put it back into the database: your call ;).

Comment: well when you say it like that! :P I will no doubt address it later on but for now this works for me and I can figure out how to get it working, thank you for the recommendation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what are you want is like this:

```
$str = "'".implode(",'", $post)."'";
echo $str;
```

Comment: This is still only returning a single result. EDIT: Ignore that, I moved the echo command and it echo'd both entries, thanks a lot for this!